# Can I use .mdf file (sql 2005 express) on machine without sql express installation

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible that, I can use sql express .mdf file in our desktop project and deploy it on client's machine without sql express installation ?

If so please provide me the steps and connectionstring.

Thanks in advance.
[Anil](http://www.ade-technologies.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sql server is not access, you need to have sql server installed on the client's machine unless you want the client to connect to your server.

All connection strings can be found at http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to deploy a database that doesn't require a separate server process, then you need to use SQL Server Compact Edition instead.

Comment: compact doesn't have all the functionality from the other editions like stored procs